# 2D C++ Grid display

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

Hi guys I have a 2D array of char '-' in it and I want to print it out.

However I want to print it in a grid format so that the point (0,0) is on the bottom left of the array not the top left.

For example now it's printing:

```
0 1 2 3
1
2
3
```

and I want it to print in the way:

```
3 
2   
1
0 1 2 3
```

How can I print my array in order to act more like a graph than an array?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is what my printing function looks like

```
displayGrid(){
for(int column = 0; column<gridSize; column++){
    for(int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++){
        std::cout<<gridArray[row][column]<< " ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is how I fill the elements in my array:

```
createGrid(){
int gridSize = 50;
for(int column = 0; column<gridSize; column++){
    for(int row=0; row<gridSize; row++){
        gridArray[row][column] = empty;
    }
}
    //gridArray[0][1] = full;       first value is x, second is y. Works.

}
```

Comment: How are your actual loops are looking? It's not that hard to reverse the printing order, starting from that. May be starting over again with pencil and paper could also help.

Comment: Reverse your outerloop. Instead of 0->size-1, start with size-1 -> 0

Comment: Check out my edit I have the code I made for printing my grid. But I want it to act like a graph too, not only print like one.

Comment: ok that's a mess. If you want to populate it this way, then you don't need to print it in reverse, no? anyway add how do you populate your data

Comment: Okay. I added that too in the edit section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let your first loop start at gridSize and decrement it.
Should look similar to this:

```
displayGrid(){
for(int column = gridSize; column>=0; column--){
    for(int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++){
        std::cout<<gridArray[row][column]<< " ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried your code but it doesn't print anything and I'm not sure why. It doesn't output anything basically.

Comment: I had a typo. The condition in the for loop is actually column>=0;

Comment: `int column = gridSize` should be `int column = gridSize - 1`